# Can power supply be chained?

Tags: power-supply, rs485

In my current project, I need to communicate and supply current to 4 sensor PCBs ("S1", "S2", "S3" and "S4") from a master PCB ("M1"). I will use RS-485 to communicate between PCBs, meaning I can chain the sensors. The distance is relatively short between them (each cable is < 25 cm). M1 also provides the 5 V to all sensors, and current is relatively small (some 10s of mA at max for all sensors).

Let's suppose I have this configuration :

[image]

I am concerned about M1 providing power supply to all sensors at the same time. Is the configuration OK, or should I take specific precautions (more ground wires, seperate 5V-GND pair, etc.) ?

Comment: What lower limit supply can S4 suffer and still work? What is the resistance of the cable? What is the lower limit that M1 might be supplying (worst case)?

Comment: *Can power supply be chained?* You're not "chaining" the power supply. You're **sharing one supply between multiple loads** (the sensors). That's **perfectly normal** and done **everywhere**. Just make sure that the supply can deliver as much current as all the loads need in total (just add up all the currents that the loads need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that looks fine. the differential signalling used in RS485 very immune to power-suppy or ground noise.

one change I would make is to include RS485 termination to both ends of the bus. 
(at M1 and at S4)